# Can I define a style for one layer, taking into account a defined relationship with another? (QGIS 2.8)

Tags: qgis, style, attribute-joins, relates

I have two sets of data. A large set of lines with a line_ref field, and a small data-only (no geometry) table with a matching line_ref field (let's say for argument's sake that the data-only table marks recently surveyed sections of pipeline). I'm talking a about a one-to-one relationship on this occasion.

I'm using QGIS 2.8

I can specify a table join, and refer to the joined data from the data-only table in styling the lines.

I can do fancy things with input forms based instead on setting up a relation in the project properties.

What I was wondering was whether I could style the lines based on the relation (rather than specifying a join). I'm prepared to be told that this isn't a sensible thing to do if that's the case.... but I'm thinking ahead to when I start to want to style things where there's a one-to-many relationship. Surely at this point table joins start to get more complex?

Comment: I guess that you should use the join-based solution. While thinkg on symbolyzing based on one-to-many relations, I wonder that even if you could form a sort of relation ship class; you won't be able to display "many" symbologies for one line; then a glimsp into your data and a better understand of its nature would spread more light on this case

Comment: I'm not currently working on a one-to-many relationship, but I have in the past. I'm thinking that the specifics of my here aren't relevant (this is a common situation). But key to the issue is that the 'many' side does not have any geometry. To be fair I'm beginning to think that this is another side to a question I asked previously ( http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/133919/how-do-i-count-the-matching-many-entries-in-a-one-to-many-relationship ) although I didn't initially think it was. Perhaps the answer is: "No this can't be done, use a join or other techniques."

Comment: Interesting question I also have in my head. Let's say we have a layer A we want to style based on attributes in another related layer B. The relation is 1-N. We could imagine we create a rule which always return one row of layer B for every row of layer A. It could be based on a date attribute and we want the latest for example. This way we don't need to join layers, we just create the relation and style based on it.

Comment: Useful example - interesting thought.

Answer (score 1):

In QGIS 2.18 we now have the `relation_aggregate` function. It returns an aggregate value calculated using all matching child features from a layer relation. You can also use `aggregate` function which returns an aggregate value calculated using features from another layer.
Here is the [QEP](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Enhancement-Proposals/issues/59).

[image: relation_aggregate in QGIS]

Comment: So can we use this function directly in an expression leading to a style? That would be powerful and exciting.